# how to deactivate zoom on double-click using setActive(false)

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3, openlayers-6, angular-openlayers

i would like to modify the below code in a such way that it only deactivate the zoom on double-click event please.

i tried the below posted code, but it disabled all the interactions including the mouse-wheel

**code**

```
this.map.getInteractions().forEach(x => x.setActive(false));
```

Comment: try map.getInteractions().forEach(interaction => {
   if(interaction instanceof DoubleClickZoom){
    interaction.setActive(false)
   }
  })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it as shown in the follwoing code:

**code**:

```
import interactionDoubleClickZoom from 'ol/interaction/DoubleClickZoom';

    this.map.getInteractions().forEach(x => {
    if (x instanceof interactionDoubleClickZoom) {
        x.setActive(false)
    }
});
```

Comment: you could disabled it from the beginning if you set doubleClickZoom: false

Comment: @BR75 yes sure, but i do not want to have this interaction to be disabled in all the occasions. i mean i want to disable it on occurence of a specific event, otherwise it remains

Answer (score 0):

You could disable default behaviour on Map initialisation:

```
export default function defaultMapInteractions(): Interaction[] {
    return defaultInteractions({
        doubleClickZoom: false,
        shiftDragZoom: false,
        dragPan: false,
        altShiftDragRotate: true,
        keyboard: false,
    }).extend([
        new DragPan({
            condition: (event) => {
                return (
                    
                    (primaryAction(event) && (noModifierKeys(event) || altKeyOnly(event))) ||

                
                    (event.originalEvent as PointerEvent).button === 1
                );
            },
        }),
    ]).getArray();
}
```

....

```
this.map = new olMap({
            interactions: [
                ...defaultMapInteractions(),
            ],....
```